# Is there any way to get the default gateway IP on iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ip, gateway

I’m having some issues to get the default gateway IP on iOS using swift. I found an application on apple store called 'Net Analyzer' that can get the default gateway IP as you can see on the image below.

[image]

On the screen shot you can see the Default Gateway IP, The DNS Server IP and the device IP address. Can anyone give me a clue how to do it?

Currently I can get the device interfaces to get the device IP, but I want to get the default gateway that the device is connected.

I'm using the current code to get the interfaces addresses

```
func getIFAddresses() -> [String] {
        var addresses = [String]()

        // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return [] }
        guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return [] }

        // For each interface ...
        for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
            let flags = Int32(ptr.pointee.ifa_flags)
            let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr.pointee

            // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
            if ((flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING)) &&
                (addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6)) {

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                if (getnameinfo(ptr.pointee.ifa_addr, socklen_t(addr.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                    let address = String(cString: hostname)
                    addresses.append(address)
                }
            }
        }

        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        return addresses
    }
```

By the way, is there any way to diff the Wi-Fi interface from the Mobile Network interface?

Comment: This is Objective-C, but probably a good starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440193/4475605

Comment: I'll take a look. thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the Gateway

If you have the ability to be in iOS ≥ 13, you can use the [`Network`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) framework.

The [`NWPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpath) you get from the [`NWPathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor/2998735-pathupdatehandler) will have the [`NWPath.gateways`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpath/3200462-gateways) variable set to the gateways IPs.

```swift
let monitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .wifi)
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    print(path.gateways)
}
monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "nwpathmonitor.queue"))
```

### Diff the Wi-Fi interface from the Mobile Network Interface

The `ptr.pointee.ifa_name` contains the interface name. The interface name will be `en0` for the WiFi interface, and `pdp_ip0` for the cell interface.  It is a `cString` so `let interfaceName = String(cString: ptr.pointee.ifa_name)` will convert it to a swift `String`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want. Is there similar handy method/approach when iOS < 12, otherwise we need to deal with the network interface.

Comment: The truly awesome `Network` framework was not added till 12 :( < 12 needs to use the inet functions in the other answers.

Comment: The `gateways` property is iOS13+.

Comment: @Popmedic Thanks. Can we also get IP address of the connected Access Point in iOS?

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix The external IP address of the Access Point?  This would be your best bet, be careful with the load balancer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234861/correct-way-of-getting-clients-ip-addresses-from-http-request

Comment: @Popmedic : Thanks, but it seems the solution is not for iOS specifically. Can you please help me with this in iOS?

Comment: @akshada-systematix sorry I do not feel your question is related to this question, please start a new thread with your question, I am sure someone will help you.

Comment: @Popmedic: I already posted this question in separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706948/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-router-in-swift-ios

I have redirected to this question from one of the answers I got there. So, Can you please help me with my doubts?

Comment: @Popmedic: I just want to know how I can get ip address of dhcp server iOS Swift?

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix There is no Swift way to do this that I know about.  The simple way is to make a  http call to a service like [whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), or create your own servers that does it.  [This post shows the technique using objective c.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361023/get-public-ip-in-objective-c/14448134)

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix https://gist.github.com/popmedic/cbdfa9da7287d4dd085d758301a1e64f